# jquery drag and drop multi-item grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop many lines between three grids. I want to choose the lines by clicking a checkbox in front of each line and then drag and drop them to another grid. My example works for only one line. Can anyone help me to implement the multiline drag and drop for a gridview. You can see my code below.

Html code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOAVerifies" runat="server" CssClass="drag_drop_grid GridDest" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Box" >
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID ="chkVerifies" Text="text" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom" HeaderText="Nom" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Categorie_Juridique" HeaderText="Catégorie Juridique" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Actions" HeaderText="Actions" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Html genarated code

```
   <table class="drag_drop_grid GridDest ui-sortable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th scope="col">Check Box</th><th scope="col">Nom</th><th scope="col">Catégorie Juridique</th><th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl02_chkVerifies" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAVerifies$ctl02$chkVerifies"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl02_chkVerifies">text</label>
                                </td><td>OA1</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Voir</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl03_chkVerifies" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAVerifies$ctl03$chkVerifies"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl03_chkVerifies">text</label>
                                </td><td>OA2</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Voir</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl04_chkVerifies" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAVerifies$ctl04$chkVerifies"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl04_chkVerifies">text</label>
                                </td><td>OA3</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Voir</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl05_chkVerifies" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAVerifies$ctl05$chkVerifies"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl05_chkVerifies">text</label>
                                </td><td>OA4</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Voir</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl06_chkVerifies" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAVerifies$ctl06$chkVerifies"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAVerifies_ctl06_chkVerifies">text</label>
                                </td><td>OA5</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Voir</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
<table class="drag_drop_grid GridDest ui-sortable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAConditions" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th scope="col">Check Box</th><th scope="col">Nom</th><th scope="col">Catégorie Juridique</th><th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAConditions_ctl02_chkConditions" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAConditions$ctl02$chkConditions"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAConditions_ctl02_chkConditions">text</label>
                                </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
<table class="drag_drop_grid GridDest ui-sortable" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAErreur" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th scope="col">Check Box</th><th scope="col">Nom</th><th scope="col">Catégorie Juridique</th><th scope="col">Actions</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAErreur_ctl02_chkErreur" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucOrganismesAssocies$gvOAErreur$ctl02$chkErreur"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucOrganismesAssocies_gvOAErreur_ctl02_chkErreur">text</label>
                                </td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

css code

```
<style type="text/css">
        .GridSrc td
        {
            background-color: #A1DCF2;
            color: black;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: Arial;
            line-height: 200%;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .GridSrc th
        {
            background-color: #3AC0F2;
            color: White;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height: 200%;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .GridDest td
        {
            background-color: #eee !important;
            color: black;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height: 200%;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .GridDest th
        {
            background-color: #6C6C6C !important;
            color: White;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height: 200%;
            width: 100px;
        }
         .selected {
          background:red !important;
        }
        .hidden {
          display:none;
        }
    </style>
```

jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#chkVerifies').change(function () {
                alert("hi");
                if (this.checked) {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                    alert(selected);
                }
                
            }); 
            
            $(".drag_drop_grid").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'crosshair',
                connectWith: '.drag_drop_grid',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: true,
                receive: function (e, ui) {
                    $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                }
            });
            
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you add html generated of your asp code ?

Comment: Hello, I have added the generated code

Comment: Hi i run your code drag drop is working fine ? Please can you elaborate more on your problem ?